# DroidCam Ubuntu 14.04 Error

Tags: 14.04, dpkg

I tried installing DroidCam for my Ubuntu, and unfortunately, things went wrong. I ran `sudo apt-get install droidcam` and it failed to install.

Whenever I try to install something else, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up droidcam (1.3-0ubuntu0) ...
tar: *.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
dpkg: error processing package droidcam (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 droidcam
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

`sudo apt-get purge droidcam`

And you can use `apt` again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I first uninstalled by using :

```
sudo apt-get remove droidcam && apt-get autoremove
```

Then I followed the following instructions to install on Linux (I tried it on Ubuntu 14.04).

https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linuxx/

Hope it helps.